# How to ensure SELECTing new records doesn't miss any records?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `mytable` that is continuously being updated with new records.
I'm trying to get the most recent records using the method below ([lastId] is largest id of the previous select):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE id > [lastId]
ORDER BY id DESC
```

But I believe ids (and timestamps if I use it) are not necessarily inserted in order so there is a (small) possibility of missing some records. How can I get around this?

--EDIT--

The `id` field is AUTOINCREMENT.

Comment: Make another column that informs whether the row has been processed or not?

Comment: provide the table structure ? i want to know there is any updated by column?

Comment: Why do you think that order of insertion has anything to do with comparing the value of the column?

Comment: If the `id` field is 'autoincrement', why do you think 'there is a (small) possibility of missing some records'?

Comment: @ketan Correct me if I'm wrong but if there is a script that starts a transaction, inserts a record, waits for 10s then commits, a record inserted by another script within that 10s will have an id greater than the former.

Comment: I don't see a problem here whatsoever, if `id` is `auto_increment` then there's no possibility of you missing any relevant data that's ready for reading. You don't have a problem at all.

Comment: @N.B. But I need to SELECT all the newest records including those that weren't ready for reading before?

Comment: If they're not ready for reading, you can't read them. If transaction didn't commit, you can't have the data. That's the point, isn't it? The issue is in the procedure that you chose for reading sadly. I know it's not helping your proposed problem, but that's how it is. Yes, a transaction can get the lower id value and not be written and if it's not written you can't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a timestamp to the table and let the process that inserts records insert with current time?

Comment: If there is a script that starts a transaction, inserts a record, waits for 10s then commits, a record inserted by another script within that 10s will have a created_at timestamp greater than the former, which will be "missed" by the SELECT.

Comment: Then you have a fubar architecture. Please re-think.